# Rewrite subdomain to subdirectory in Apache .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Suppose I have a domain called `example.com` and I want to use rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file of Apache to rewrite:

`https://office.example.com/index.html`

to

`https://example.com/office/index.html`.

How would I do that? I checked lots of answers here, and the solution seems to be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^office.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/office/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This works when I test it here:

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=b40ca72f-86d3-5452-a04b-ac9f24812c57

Regrettably, it does generate an error 500 on my server. I enabled logging and found that this seems to be a recursion problem:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects.
```

In the logs it seems to add `office` to `office` endlessly: `/office/office/office/...`. I have no idea why this is happening. The rewritten URL doesn't meet the rewrite condition, so why would it do this?

I have found a way to make it "work". If I add `R=301` to the RewriteRule attributes it does a redirect, and works, but I would prefer if the original URL remained in the address bar.

Here's the log for the first 2 redirects:

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/'
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/'
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/'
pass through /
[perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/ -> 
[perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
[perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] rewrite '' -> 'https://example.com/office/'
reduce https://example.com/office/ -> /office/
[perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /office/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
#1 init rewrite engine with requested uri /office/
#1 applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/office/'
#1 applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/office/'
#1 applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/office/'
#1 pass through /office/
#1 [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/office/
#1 [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'office/'
#1 [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] rewrite 'office/' -> 'https://example.com/office/office/'
#1 reduce https://example.com/office/office/ -> /office/office/
#1 [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /office/office/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
#2 init rewrite engine with requested uri /office/office/
#2 applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/office/office/'
#2 applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/office/office/'
#2 applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/office/office/'
#2 pass through /office/office/
#2 [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/office
#2 [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/office/
#2 [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'office/office/'
#2 [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] rewrite 'office/office/' -> 'https://example.com/office/office/off
#2 reduce https://example.com/office/office/office/ -> /office/office/office/
#2 [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /office/office/office/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/office/$1 [L,NC,QSA]` - this should already result in an external 302 redirect (as if `R=302` was used), not a rewrite? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? Where does the subdomain point to on the filesystem?

Comment: @MrWhite: There are no other directives in the `.htaccess` file. The subdomain is an alias of the main domain. So without the `.htaccess` file `office.example.com` would be the same as `example.com`.

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: @MrWhite: Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^office.example.com$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/office/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
> ```

Rather confusing, this should *implicitly* trigger an external 302 (temporary) redirect, not an *internal rewrite* - when specifying a different host in the substitution string to the one being requested. (Although in my experience, *any* absolute URL in the substitution string triggers an external redirect.)

If it does trigger an internal rewrite (as indicated by the logs) then the requested hostname does not change (since this is not a separate request) and you will indeed get a rewrite loop.

However, if "the subdomain is an alias of the main domain" and a rewrite is what's required, then there is no need to specify a hostname in the *substitution* string and you will indeed need to make additional checks to prevent an internal rewrite loop (500 error).

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^office\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^office office%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

...to exclude any requests (including rewritten requests) that already start `/office`.

No need for the `NC` and `QSA` flags.

Alternatively, to only target direct requests (not rewritten requests) you could check the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable instead (which is empty on the initial request and set to "200", as in 200 OK, after the first successful rewrite).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^office\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) office/$1 [L]
```

This has the added "benefit" that you can potentially have a sub-subdirectory called `/office` as well. ie. `/office/office`.

**UPDATE:** A third version is to check against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable. However, I would not expect this to be any different from the first version above.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^office\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/office
RewriteRule ^ office%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

> Sadly enough, both your suggestions gave the same error as before.

Two things to try...

- Add a slash prefix on the substitution string. ie. `/office%{REQUEST_URI}` and `/office/$1` respectively. This changes the substitution string into a URL-path, rather than a relative filesystem path. However, I wouldn't necessarily expect this to make any difference in this respect. (It would be required for an external redirect.)
- Use the `END` flag instead of `L` on the `RewriteRule` directives - this is an Apache 2.4 addition that should halt all processing. The `L` flag "only" ends the current pass before restarting the rewriting process (hence the need for additional checks to prevent rewrite loops).

> But now any other file (IMG, CSS) gives an 404.

The above rewrites *everything*, so it will naturally rewrite all static resources if they don't already start `/office`. (If they already start `/office` then they should already be excluded by the above rules.)

To exclude common resources, you could make an exception (an additional `RewriteCond` directive) to exclude specific file extensions. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$
```

And/or add an additional `RewriteCond` directive to exclude requests that already map to physical files (although this is "marginally" more *expensive*). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

### Summary:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^office\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) office/$1 [END]
```

Comment: I find your reason for the loop very plausible, if it is a rewrite it might very well still be looking at the same hostname. I will read on and try your suggestions.

Comment: Just to add, if you've previously experimented with `R=301` (_permanent_) redirects then you will need to make sure your browser cache is cleared before testing.

Comment: Yes, I did empty the cache on every test. Sadly enough, both your suggestions gave the same error as before. I tested it twice to be sure. However, now that I know what the reason of the loop is, I have a better chance of solving this.

Comment: "both your suggestions gave the same error" - hmm, that is very strange. The first rule only rewrites requests that do not start with `/office` (ie. `!^office`). The `REQUEST_URI` var contains the full URL-path (including the slash prefix). So, after the first rewrite, the requested URL is updated and should now start `/office` and the rule is bypassed.

Comment: Two things to try... use a slash prefix on the substitution string. ie. `/office%{REQUEST_URI}` and `/office/$1` respectively. This changes the substitution string into a URL-path, rather than a relative filesystem path. This should not be required for an internal rewrite. And/or use the `END` flag instead of `L`  on the `RewriteRule` directives - this is a Apache 2.4 addition that should halt all processing. The `L` flag "only" ends the current pass before restarting the rewriting process (hence the need for additional checks to prevent rewrite loops).

Comment: Adding the slash prefix didn't change anything but the END seems to do something. It's no longer looping and I get the correct HTML. But now any other file (IMG, CSS) gives an 404. This is a step forward. This is true for both suggestions.

Comment: The above does rewrite _everything_, including all static resources. However, do these static resources already include `/office` in the URL?

Comment: Yes, I thought the same thing. I'm looking into that now, I'm sure I can work that out. Can you add the `END` in your answer, then I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not very experienced with the stuff. Have to do it once in a blue moon.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer. I've also added a 3rd version that checks against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable (although I wouldn't necessarily expect this to work any better). And also addressed the issue of IMG and CSS files being rewritten.

Comment: I solved it slightly different. Since I only need HTML files to be redirected I did `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)\.html$ [NC]` and then `RewriteRule (.*) $1 [END]` and now it works.

Comment: Yes, (that rule would need to go first) to prevent all other files being rewritten (it essentially prevents any other directives that follow being processed). However, it would be preferable to write that in a single directive. For example: `RewriteRule !\.html$ - [END]` - the single hyphen (as the 2nd argument) indications _no substitution_. Whereas `RewriteRule (.*) $1 [END]` rewrites to itself.